# Are these commands deprecated in MS CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Are these syntax deprecated in MS CRM?
1. Mscrm.InlineEditUtilities.tryResetFocusOnActiveControl();
2. Mscrm.InternalUtilities._Script.alert
3. Xrm.Internal.getResourceString
4. Mscrm.InlineEditUtilities.

If deprecated, can someone help me with the information on updated syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why it’s unsupported/non-recommended to use undocumented/Internal syntax in Dynamics CRM.

Use only available documented CRM SDK stuffs to avoid surprises.

Edit:
To open a popup & show progress in a supported way, I’ll use `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource()` and show some html animation & do the background process.

Comment: Could you please help me with the documented CRM SDK stuff... and any idea on how to show Progress of an action. Eg: I am using Email to Case, using a web resource. When user clicks on Convert To Case, I want to show "Converting to Case..."